How to identify old rc car receiver circuit
That circuit is not even labelled and also wire connected to it is detached , I wanna know where to connect motors and batterys, and also whether the circuit is working or not

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A wire with only one end connected is quite possibly the receiver antenna

what circuit are you talking about?
